# How does zope/plone evaluate variables?

Tags: plone, zope, template-tal, zpt

Imagine this scenario:

I have a ZPT in Zope where I define, into a metal block, a global variable.
This variable takes its value from an expression like this

```
global myVar id | nothing;
global anotherVar 1;
```

where `nothing` could be replaced with `python:0` or `python:False` or `None` and so on.

Now imagine that into another block, I'll do something like

```
global myVar2 myVar | anotherVar | nothing;
```

where `nothing` could be everything that I specified above.

Now suppose that `id` hasn't a value and so `myVar` took `nothing` (or the other possible values; it's makes not difference at all).
What I expected was that `myVar2` took `anotherVar`'s value, since `anotherVar` has a value. But with great surprise, I notice that this isn't true and `myVar2` took `myVar` value; that means `nothing`.

If I understand what is happening, I'll suppose that this kind of statement only control over **existence** of that variable and not over it's value.

Obviously I can make that kind of statement into a pythonic way and, of course, it works "well" (namely, as I expected)
So, someone can confirm or disprove what I suppose there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is not Plone or Zope specific, you are dealing with a [TALES statement](http://wiki.zope.org/ZPT/TALESSpecification13) here, which, together with TAL and METAL form the page template language implemented by Zope Page Templates (and, incidentally, also by [chameleon](/questions/tagged/chameleon), plus several other implementations in different programming languages).

You are using a TALES path expression when you use the `|` character, and it is *not* the same as a Python `or` expression. Each path named in the expression will by resolved, and only *if it doesn't exist* will the next path be used. From the specification:

> When a TALES path expression is evaluated, it attempts to traverse each path, from left to right, until it succeeds or runs out of paths.

Since all your paths resolve to existing variable names, they all exist and the first one will be used, regardless of it's value.

You want to use a `python:` expression instead:

```
myVar2 python:myVar or anotherVar or None;
```

Note that in TAL there rarely is a need for the `global` keyword. You probably want to define these items on your root element of your document instead; variables are visible within the same scope as the XML or HTML element they are defined on:

```
<html tal:define="myVar id | nothing; anotherVar 1;">
  <!-- myVar and anotherVar are visible in the whole HTML document -->
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer that is the best possible imho. I didn't read with attention Tales evaluations, so probably, i lost this step. ABOUT `global` we use macro expansion and we notice that, if we don't define this variables with that scope, we're not able to use them in other section of the same page....

Comment: Macros just incorporate the included TAL into the same document on execution, so the same namespace is used. Are you sure you are at the same nested context in those other sections?

Comment: I'll work with this project as an "external" developer: the base was developed before I went here. So, no, I'm not sure about this but i found that the only way for let the things works (with Macros and so on) is this.